# Moving an std::string into a boost::thread in C++03

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, stdstring, boost-move

I'm using boost 1.51 on multiple platforms and compilers without C++11.

In my main thread I have a very long, expensive to copy, `std::string` `veryLongString`, that I need to pass to a new thread for processing.
After the new thread is created I have no more use for `veryLongString` on the main thread so I'd like to *move* it into the `boost::thread` ctor.
The main thread, or the scope of `veryLongString` may end before the new thread completes, so passing by reference (e.g. with `boost::ref`) is not an option.

Obviously, if `veryLongString` was created as a `shared_ptr<std::string>` then I could just copy the `shared_ptr` into the thread ctor, but it wasn't, so I'd need to copy it anyway.

How can I `[boost::]move()` `veryLongString` into the `boost::thread` ctor (probably using via `boost::bind`)?
Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely. 
But if I do, then once the main thread goes out of scope veryLongString goes along with it, destroying the string and creating a dangling ref inside the new thread. 
I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: It's sounds like you create a thread for some special processing, and not a "daemon" thread that is detached from the main thread. Therefore the scenario that the main thread would exit before the processing threads sound suspicious.

Comment: As for your problem, why not pass the string as a reference to the constructor, and in the constructor use `boost::move` to move the contents to an internal string?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: actually, it is an async call that is sent off to do it's work. It will call a completion handler/continuation when it's done. The main thread, does not really exit but `veryLongString` does go out of scope to handle other things.  
BUT, I was using a function to do the work. If I use an callable-object I can do what you suggested, I don't know why I didn't think of that! I don't even need `boost::mov`e, I can just `swap` the strings. Put your 2nd comment as an answer and I'll mark it as *the* answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is expensive to copy, pass something holding it but less expensive to copy. For example, you can use a `shared_ptr<std::string>`. You can pass the shared pointer to a suitable wrapper which calls the function you actually want to get called (and probably taking the argument by reference or `const` reference).

To get the string into a shared pointer you might need to move it there:

```
shared_ptr<std::string> ptr(new std::string);
ptr->swap(your_long_string);
```

Comment: This, indeed, works fine. Just a small optimization is to use `shared_ptr<std::string> ptr = make_shared<std::string>()` instead of `new`.

Comment: Wouldn't the implementation of swap still make a copy on non c++11 compilers? So solving the issues mentioned?

Comment: The copy is of the `shared_ptr` not the `std::string`. So momentarily the ref. count will be 2, until the calling thread instance goes out of scope.

Comment: I might completely miss the point here, but if swap was called on the shared_ptr it should be called like ptr.swap(your_long_string). That would not compile since your_long_string is not a shared_ptr.

Comment: There are two `swap()` which could be used: `ptr.swap(p)` would swap shared pointers, `ptr->swap(s)` swaps the pointed to string with another string. `std::string` has a `swap()` member just exchanging the internal pointers (unless there are small strings involved which may require moving characters).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as a reference to the constructor, and in the constructor use `move` (or even `swap`) to "move" the string.

Comment: I just tried this. It is not as simple as I initially thought. Although the string is "moved" into the functor, passing the functor into the thread requires a functor copy (can't pass by ref), so that I need to write a special copy-ctor that actually moves it instead of copying.